# pandas randomly replace k percent

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

having a simple pandas data frame with 2 columns e.g. `id` and `value` where `value` is either `0` or `1` I would like to randomly replace `10%` of all `value==1` with `0`.

How can I achieve this behaviour with pandas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

***`pandas` answer***

- use `query` to get filtered `df` with only `value == 1`
- use `sample(frac=.1)` to take 10% of those
- use the index of the result to assign zero

---

```
df.loc[
    df.query('value == 1').sample(frac=.1).index,
    'value'
] = 0
```

---

***alternative `numpy` answer***

- get boolean array of where `df['value']` is `1`
- assign random array of 10% zeros and 90% ones

---

```
v = df.value.values == 1
df.loc[v, 'value'] = np.random.choice((0, 1), v.sum(), p=(.1, .9))
```

Comment: You becoming `query` function sponsor :-)

Comment: @Boud I tend to focus on a particular feature and answer many questions with it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a NumPy approach with [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) -

```
a = df.value.values  # get a view into value col
idx = np.flatnonzero(a) # get the nonzero indices

# Finally select unique 10% from those indices and set 0s there
a[np.random.choice(idx,size=int(0.1*len(idx)),replace=0)] = 0
```

Sample run -

```
In [237]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,(100,2)),columns=['id','value'])

In [238]: (df.value==1).sum() # Original Count of 1s in df.value column
Out[238]: 53

In [239]: a = df.value.values

In [240]: idx = np.flatnonzero(a)

In [241]: a[np.random.choice(idx,size=int(0.1*len(idx)),replace=0)] = 0

In [242]: (df.value==1).sum() # New count of 1s in df.value column
Out[242]: 48
```

---

Alternatively, a bit more pandas approach -

```
idx = np.flatnonzero(df['value'])
df.ix[np.random.choice(idx,size=int(0.1*len(idx)),replace=0),'value'] = 0
```

---

**Runtime test**

All approaches posted thus far -

```
def f1(df):  #@piRSquared's soln1
    df.loc[df.query('value == 1').sample(frac=.1).index,'value'] = 0

def f2(df):  #@piRSquared's soln2
    v = df.value.values == 1
    df.loc[v, 'value'] = np.random.choice((0, 1), v.sum(), p=(.1, .9))

def f3(df): #@Roman Pekar's soln
    idx = df.index[df.value==1]
    df.loc[np.random.choice(idx, size=idx.size/10, replace=False)].value = 0

def f4(df): #@Mine soln1
    a = df.value.values
    idx = np.flatnonzero(a)
    a[np.random.choice(idx,size=int(0.1*len(idx)),replace=0)] = 0

def f5(df): #@Mine soln2
    idx = np.flatnonzero(df['value'])
    df.ix[np.random.choice(idx,size=int(0.1*len(idx)),replace=0),'value'] = 0
```

Timings -

```
In [2]: # Setup inputs
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,(10000,2)),columns=['id','value'])
   ...: df1 = df.copy()
   ...: df2 = df.copy()
   ...: df3 = df.copy()
   ...: df4 = df.copy()
   ...: df5 = df.copy()
   ...: 

In [3]: # Timings
   ...: %timeit f1(df1)
   ...: %timeit f2(df2)
   ...: %timeit f3(df3)
   ...: %timeit f4(df4)
   ...: %timeit f5(df5)
   ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 3.96 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 844 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.62 ms per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 163 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 663 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

you can probably use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
>>> idx = df.index[df.value==1]
>>> df.loc[np.random.choice(idx, size=idx.size/10, replace=False)].value = 0
```

Comment: the OP wants to randomly replace only the rows that are `1`, not a random sample of the entire df

Comment: yep I missed that, going to change the answer